# Failed to load SSL keystore of type JKS for secured kafka topic

Tags: ssl, jmeter, jks

Firstly, we are trying to send the Kafka messages using this JMeter for sasl_ssl enabled Kafka. So, for that purpose we have created a thread group(https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3OLH.png) in that we have added Kafka producer sampler(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBa2k.png), Kafka producer config(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShTrq.png).

1. In Kafka producer sampler I have added the variable name, Kafka topic and the payload message we want to send.
2. In Kafka producer config we have added Kafka broker i.e., host name and added the sasl.jaas.config and its value.
3. Now when we started running the JMeter we are getting the error like failed to load SSL keystore of type JKS. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/krfFo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to read [documentation](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) which states:

> For example to enable SSL properties you can add below properties
>
> ```
> _ssl.key.password
> _ssl.keystore.location
> _ssl.keystore.password
> _ssl.keystore.type
> _ssl.truststore.location
> _ssl.truststore.password
> _ssl.truststore.type
> ```
>
> Note: These are just sample properties, SSL properties are already included in kafka sampler.

You need to modify the properties to point to your keystore and make sure that the keystore contains the certificate required for secure connection to Kafka, the certificate can be added either using [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) or [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/)

[image]

More information: [How to Do Kafka Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/kafka-testing)